# aws iot describe-endpoint::You must specify a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-cli, aws-iot

I am following [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-sdk-node.html) for connecting Raspberry Pi to AWS IoT using Node.js SDK and I have done all the other steps but I am lost in the authentication and certificate step:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aws iot describe-endpoint
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: 
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]: 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
2016-02-24-204612_1920x1080_scrot.png  Desktop     get-pip.py           node_modules  python_games             sources    WiringPi
aws                                    device.cfg  ibm                  Pictures      python-iot-raspberry-pi  Templates
aws-iot-device-sdk-js                  Documents   iot_1.0-1_armhf.deb  projects      root                     Videos
certs                                  Downloads   Music                Public        root.pem                 wiringPi

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd certs/
pi@raspberrypi:~/certs $ ls
1cf77402f9-certificate.pem.crt  1cf77402f9-private.pem.key  1cf77402f9-public.pem.key
```

When I browse to https://A34SXNTM6AT7XH.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/things/MyNewThing/shadow or https://A34SXNTM6AT7XH.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com I see `Missing Authentication Token` message:
[image]

I am not sure how to get the last step working so I could see stuff in the URLs when I browse to them. Can someone help me figure which steps I am missing or is missing from the tutorial?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

- Browse to
  https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#security_credential
  and then if you don’t have a key click on create new access key and
  if you already have it save the information and enter it in front of
  entries of `aws configure` command and also for region select
  “us-west-2” is Oregon is selected in your dashboard.
- After that you will be able to see the credential in the following:
  The AWS credentials file – located at `~/.aws/credentials` on Linux, OS
  X, or Unix